# Why does my background image for div disappear?

Tags: css, html, background-image

I'm creating a div(has a background image) that contains 2 divs inside it. The div with the background image disappears when I add a float left to the div's inside.

Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Linear Gradient as Background Image</h2>
    <p>This linear gradient starts at the top. It starts red, transitioning to yellow:</p>

    <div id="grad1" style="background-image: URL(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Awesome-Gradient-Background-.jpg); width:100%; margin-top:50">
           <div style="width:55%; padding: 10px; float:left;">
                <img alt="abc" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Blue_computer_icon.svg" style="max-width: 75%; height: auto; margin:10%; " />
           </div>
           <div style="width:35%;padding: 10px;float:left;">
                <h1 style="color:black; margin-top: 70px; font-weight:bolder; text-align:left;">
                Header<br>
                    <h3 style="color:red; text-align:left;">(Subtitle)</h3>
                </h1>
                <p style="color:black;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
                    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
               </p>
          </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using inline CSS? Just create a style file and link it in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

The element needs a height: In your example the div with the id grad1 has a height of 0px.

```
<div id="grad1" style="background-image: URL(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Awesome-Gradient-Background-.jpg); width:100%; margin-top:50; height:200px">
       <div style="width:55%; padding: 10px; float:left;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eza2zag4/

**The reason why the element have a height of 0px is because you wrote`float: left` in the child element**

If you put a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after the childs, the element have the ideal height.

https://jsfiddle.net/eza2zag4/1/

Comment: Typo error, it must be: <div style="clear: both;"></div> works fine. You don't need to height

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of `div` with an `id="grad1"` for example 100px and you background image will appear.

Answer (score 0):

if you give a height to the div 'grad1', then it will work.

```css
html, body
{
  height:100%;
}
#grad1
{
  height:100%;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Linear Gradient as Background Image</h2>
    <p>This linear gradient starts at the top. It starts red, transitioning to yellow:</p>

    <div id="grad1" style="background-image: URL(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Awesome-Gradient-Background-.jpg); width:100%; margin-top:50;">
           <div style="width:55%; padding: 10px; float:left;">
                <img alt="abc" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Blue_computer_icon.svg" style="max-width: 75%; height: auto; margin:10%; " />
           </div>
           <div style="width:35%;padding: 10px;float:left;">
                <h1 style="color:black; margin-top: 70px; font-weight:bolder; text-align:left;">
                Header<br>
                    <h3 style="color:red; text-align:left;">(Subtitle)</h3>
                </h1>
                <p style="color:black;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
                    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
               </p>
          </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code then use the `display: flex;` to the background image.

or else check my updated answer.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
  #grad1{
    background-image: URL(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Awesome-Gradient-Background-.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top:50;
   /* display: flex;*/
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Linear Gradient as Background Image</h2>
    <p>This linear gradient starts at the top. It starts red, transitioning to yellow:</p>

    <div id="grad1">
           <div style="width:55%; padding: 10px; float:left;">
                <img alt="abc" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Blue_computer_icon.svg" style="max-width: 75%; height: auto; margin:10%; " />
           </div>
           <div style="width:35%;padding: 10px;float:left;">
                <h1 style="color:black; margin-top: 70px; font-weight:bolder; text-align:left;">
                Header<br>
                    <h3 style="color:red; text-align:left;">(Subtitle)</h3>
                </h1>
                <p style="color:black;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
                    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
                    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
               </p>
          </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main div not wrapping floated child elements. Add below code in your css.

```
#grad1:after{
  content:"";
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  visibility:hidden;
  height:0;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Note: First Save the image in the same directory like that:

www => index.html , back.jpg

www is a folder name:

always used style tag for styling the html elements or the best choice is to create a new file for styling purpose style.css or 'anyname'.css this is the good pratice.

you can prefer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <style>
            #grad1 {
                background-image: url('back.jpg');
                background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
                padding: 15px;
                width: 550px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Linear Gradient as Background Image</h2>
        <p>This linear gradient starts at the top. It starts red, transitioning to yellow:</p>

        <div id="grad1">
               <div style="width:55%; padding: 10px;">
                    <img alt="abc" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Blue_computer_icon.svg" style="max-width: 75%; height: auto; margin:10%; " />
               </div>
               <div style="width:35%;padding: 10px;float:left;">
                    <h1 style="color:black; margin-top: 70px; font-weight:bolder; text-align:left;">
                    Header<br>
                        <h3 style="color:red; text-align:left;">(Subtitle)</h3>
                    </h1>
                    <p style="color:black;">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
                        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
                        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                        esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
                        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
                        officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                   </p>
              </div>
           </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```